# Story about Gargacharya revealing to Shri Krishna the truth about his birth

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, puranas, krishna, bhagavata-purana

Sadguru once said that "Then Gargacharya thought it was time to reveal the truth about Krishna’s birth. He spoke about the prophecy that Naradamuni had made and revealed to him for the first time that he was not Nanda’s and Yashodha’s son."

He did not provide any references so can anyone help me locate from which scriptures did Sadhguru quote this story from??

Comment: Not an authentic claim. Garga is only responsible for naming Krishna and Baladeva. Rather than Krishna, he tells Nanda that his son (Krishna) is like Narayana. As for the revelation about not being Nanda Yashoda’s son, in a way it was done by Akrura, not Garga. As said Garga restricted only to naming the two kids.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the answer. As you(@Adiyarkku) have said, "As for the revelation about not being Nanda Yashoda’s son, in a way it was done by Akrura, not Garga."  Can you please provide me with a reference where Akrura reveal Krsna not being Nanda Yashoda’s son so that I can know what really happened there and understand it properly? Thank you for responding once again.

Comment: Who are you referring to as Sadguru?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I'm referring to Jagadish Vasudev as sadguru who is the founder and head of the Isha Foundation, based in Coimbatore, India which was established in 1992. He operates an ashram and yoga centre that carries out educational and spiritual activities.

Comment: For your own spiritual benefit, do not fall for such self proclaimed 'gurus', who never had any formal studies under any guru. He just is a good orator, who knows how to make money. He is no Sadguru.

Comment: @.AnandSowmithiran and @Adiyarkku I agree what you both have said above (it not an authentic claim and he has not done any formal studies). Thank you for replying to my question. My concern now is what @.Adiyarkku had said "As for the revelation about not being Nanda Yashoda’s son, in a way it was done by **Akrura**, not Garga."  I was not able to find whether Akrura reveal that and may be this is because of my limited access to scriptures. Can you provide me with some references where Akrura reveal that? I apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: @abhaybandhu so see. Why I said “in a way” is because God always knows from before his origin (it can be seen from his birth story where he himself instructs Vasudeva to take him to Nanda). Akrura comes later to take Bhagavan and tells him- your parents Vasudeva Devaki are living in xyz manner under Kamsa’s rule etc etc. So “in a way” he’s informing him of his parents plight, more than per say educating him about his real parents. You can find the reference in Harivamsa and Bhagavatam